GitHub Advanced Security is not recognizing hard-coded passwords
I'm new to SAST and started performing tests in a C# repository with GitHub Advanced Security to understand the working principle. I inserted hard-coded credentials into the code, which does not recognize any security issue. Do I have to explicitly add a step to my workflow file?
namespace SecurityExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string awsAccessKeyId = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"; // Example AWS Access Key ID
            string awsSecretAccessKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"; // Example AWS Secret Access Key

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to use the following AWS credentials:");
            Console.WriteLine($"AWS Access Key ID: {awsAccessKeyId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"AWS Secret Access Key: {awsSecretAccessKey}");

            // Simulate using the AWS credentials
            UseAwsCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey);
        }

        static void UseAwsCredentials(string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKey)
        {
            // Dummy method to simulate using AWS credentials
            Console.WriteLine("Using AWS credentials...");
        }
    }
}


did you enable the GitHub Advanced Security?

I did! Everything is set up as it should
